# Appeal for bountying a few questions

Tags: discussion, bounty

As we reach the end of the year, Karsten had put up a similar appeal for good old unanswered questions to be bountied.

[Comparison of the rate of SN1 and SN2 reaction](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88579/comparison-of-the-rate-of-sn1-and-sn2-reaction/179525#179525)

[Inductive effect on stability of free radical](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81343/inductive-effect-on-stability-of-free-radical/179556#179556)

These two questions had intrigued me and I answered them. I am confident of their correctness too.

Yet ChemSE being a site of great academicians I know that there's someone who knows better than me.

So I would like to bounty them but since I've answered them, 100rep is the minimum spend and that cost is an arm and a leg for me.

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grace period on the bounty on the first question had not ended when the meta question was posted. See the [rules regarding bounties](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). You could have waited a while before making this request. Also, you may explain why a fresh bounty should be offered on a post that was recently bountied and seems to have received plenty of attention.

Your answer to the second post seems reasonable, I don't see any shortcomings and also don't understand why you see the need for a bounty. See again the purpose behind bounties:

[image]

Comment: Why I wanted a bounty on both questions is because I wanted somebody more knowledgeable than me (I'm just in Year 12 in India) to answer that question (more deeper than myself).

Comment: I was close to have received a bounty on my answer to the first question, just missed it by 1 vote.

Comment: @HarikrishnanM A bounty is assigned to an answer by the person who offers the bounty. I don't see much to add to my answer here. I don't really understand your motivation for this request, although it seems you are looking for a canonical answer or authoritative reference.

Comment: The 'canonical answer / authoritative ref' is the one I am looking for.